How to change the pick up button in VR Unity HTC Vive
I'm developing a game and using the xr interaction toolkit. I have 2 created hands on which there is a script "XR Controller (Action-based)" and a layout for left and right is connected. Only for some reason, picking up items happens on the side button (HTC Vive), and not on the trigger. How to fix it?

